# create multiple columns (dummies) out of multiple answer survey question

Tags: r

How is it possible to create several (dummy) columns out of a multiple answer column? I would like to do this fully automatic so that it automatically detects the answers. a function like this: create_multiple_columns(df$posessions, sep = " ")

for illustration, it would automatically create the "hat", "table" and "pen" dummies..

```
df = data.frame(person = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                posessions = c("hat table pen", "hat", "table", "hat pen"), 
                hat = c(1,1,0,1),
                table = c(1,0,1,0),
                pen = c(1,0,0,1)
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach where reshaping the data you can get something closer to what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df2 <- structure(list(person = c(1, 2, 3, 4), posessions = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("hat", "hat pen", "hat table pen", "table"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

The code:

```
df2 %>% separate(posessions,into = c('v1','v2','v3'),sep = ' ') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -1) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(person,value) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from=N) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   person [4]
  person   hat   pen table
   <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1      1     1     1     1
2      2     1     0     0
3      3     0     0     1
4      4     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

using `data.table`:

```
df = data.table(
  person = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
  posessions = c("hat table pen", "hat", "table", "hat pen")
)

all_words <- df$posessions %>% str_split(" ") %>% unlist() %>% unique()
df[, (all_words) := map(all_words, ~str_detect(posessions, .x) * 1L)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string using `strsplit`, get `unique` words and test with `%in%` if they are there.

```
x <- strsplit(df$posessions, " ")
y <- unique(unlist(x))
z <- +(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, "%in%", x=y)))
colnames(z) <- y
cbind(df[1:2], z)
#  person    posessions hat table pen
#1      1 hat table pen   1     1   1
#2      2           hat   1     0   0
#3      3         table   0     1   0
#4      4       hat pen   1     0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit` + `table`

```
p <- strsplit(df$posessions, " ")
cbind(
  df,
  do.call(
    rbind,
    Map(
      function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(p)))),
      p
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  person    posessions hat table pen
1      1 hat table pen   1     1   1
2      2           hat   1     0   0
3      3         table   0     1   0
4      4       hat pen   1     0   1
```